# Can a colon be placed at end of page

Tags: colons

I'm reviewing a book for a friend.  He wrote the sentence, "Tom Smith relays the following anecdote about the his baby's first exposure to the zoo:"

Then the page breaks and the anecdote is on the next page.  Is it ok to have a colon at the end of a page like that?

Comment: It would be odd but will it actually appear that way when the book is printed? If you're reviewing the book presumably it's not been published yet (and the page settings may be different in the published book).

Comment: Yes, it will appear that way...he sent me the print-ready file. I circled it and made a note of your comment...that it will appear odd.

I have a few more questions about breaking the text between pages for this, but can't seem to find any sources that go over that.  Do you know of any?

Comment: Generally a publisher will attempt to avoid this by moving part of a paragraph up or down across the page break.  But there's nothing wrong with it from a syntax/semantic point of view -- it just looks a little funny.

Comment: Even if you “fix” it for the paper version avoiding the page-break afterwards, there is nothing you can realistically do for the e-book version, where the readers will change their font-sizes on a whim.

Comment: @k1eran - Actually, most word processors have algorithms that attempt to avoid "ugly" page breaks.  But I'm doubtful that many are set up to avoid this specific scenario.

Comment: Thank you all for your thoughts.  I will share them with my author friend!